# MirrorMaker2: There are no in-flight requests for node 0

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

We have set up mm2 to replicate data from an on-premise-kafka-cluster to azure eventhubs (one direction). (We have already done that in the past without any problems with two on-premise-kafka-clusters.)
Initially everything ran smoothly until we found the first errors in the log-files weeks later (probably linked to activating replication for a quite big topic).

**Problem**

We have a few of these error messages popping up regularly. Restarting the service and stopping/reenabling replication for all topics didn't help anything.

```
2023-04-12 11:47:32,787 INFO org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask: WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-102} Committing offsets
2023-04-12 11:47:32,787 INFO org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask: WorkerSourceTask{id=MirrorSourceConnector-102} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit
2023-04-12 11:47:32,789 ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender: [Producer clientId=producer-731] Uncaught error in kafka producer I/O thread:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are no in-flight requests for node 0
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.InFlightRequests.requestQueue(InFlightRequests.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.InFlightRequests.completeNext(InFlightRequests.java:70)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleCompletedReceives(NetworkClient.java:838)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:558)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:324)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

When I take a look on the older logs, I see also these ERROR messages which are probably linked to the problem:

```
Failed to flush, timed out while waiting for producer to flush outstanding 
53465 messages
.....
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer is closed forcefully
```

**Setup**

(not all of these configs are needed, we just kept them from the kafka2kafka-replication):
[image]

**What we tried so far**
We have tried to restart MM2 (the software streams-replication-manager in our case) as well as removing all topics from the whitelist before rewhitelisting them. Didn't change anything.

Next I will compare the config of all internal topics with the one from our former kafka2kafka-replication.

I have also checked kafka broker- as well as kafka connect-logs. Everything looks okay there.
No errors so far on Azure-side. But replicating big topics lagged a lot.

I have checked to which topics the producers in the log-file belong. They are connected to one of the topics which is in replication at the moment as well as (the majority) to the internal offset-sync-topic. There is a lot of inactive producers pointing to the offset-sync-topic. I have changed the min ISR for this topic to 1 just to check if the problem has anything to do with network latency. But didn't change anything, so I reverted it back to the origin 2.

Any hints where to continue troubleshooting?

Comment: If I were i could have reached out to MS support ont his issues . They have access to internal logs and can help resolve this issue .

Comment: Thanks, as MirrorMaker2 is not officially supported by Azure (Event Hubs) and log compaction is still in preview mode, I did not consider that.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already found out before me, there is obviously a bug when mirroring between Kafka and Azure Event Hubs when acks=0. Setting acks to a value higher than 0, fixes the problem.